# how to set the minimum date for JQuery datepicker retrieved from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$('#bid_work_end_date').datepicker(
   {
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
       minDate: -0
   });
```

In this code, i have set the min date as today's date but i want to set it by retrieving from a rails model. I cannot find out a way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var oDate=new Date();
var day=oDate.getDate();
var month=oDate.getMonth()+1;
var year=oDate.getFullYear();
var new_date=day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
$('#bid_work_end_date').datepicker( { dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: new_date });
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the Javascript is contained in a .js file, would it?

Comment: Yes. if the line is in your view file (html.erb), it'll be OK, but not if this is in a separate .js file (which seems to be a good practice)

Comment: i think you should go with javascript date function. it will help you

Comment: yeah, the solution is good but in my case, the min date is already there in a different model and i want to retrieve that and set it in the jquery datepicker which is a .js file. any ideas on how to do it???